# What is a good design pattern to model the API for a parallel search engine and database?

Tags: design-patterns, search, jpa, entity

(this is in a Java project)

I'm using a search engine in parallel with a relational database. The main object of interest is a 'listing'. It has approximately 5 other entities in a composition style structure. One is location, another is a complex time and date definition.

From my experience, and from research, searching is WAY faster on Solr,Lucene, Elastic SEarch than any database with full text and geographical indexes added. So, that's why I wish to use a search engine on the data that is in the data base. Also, the search engine will contain more granular time entries than the database, more concrete vs. formualaic.

So, in reference to a design pattern: The goal is to have CRUD happen from the API to both the database contents on an entity and also on all the time and geographical permutations instantiated in the search engine index.

I have had discussions with a partner and I believe he is right when he says 
To keep coupling low, that the 'Listing' class,  (again, the top of the data hierarchy in the data), should NOT know about the search engine and NOT have static functions added to it that do search on the search engine. He stated that a 'Chain of Responsibility' design pattern might be appropriate way to allow the CRUD of the API to act both on the database and the search engine contents. My read on that is that's not correct.

I have been looking on http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns and I think that the Facade pattern, http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/facade, might be best. But I'd like to hear other opinions.

Thank you in advance.

PS. I am developing an osem layer (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_Project) capable of being injected into a Spring IOC. This layer is custom made for ElasticSearch. As of yet, it doesn't support transactions or foreign keys (and may never do so). But it will have annotation hooks to develop those later. You may want to look at it. It's at https://github.com/kwince/osemManager . There are currently two branches of it underway. I'll decide which one to merger in the next week.

Comment: Either I am way off, or something has got confused her. I guess you need to break down the problem there are lots of things going on that could be parallelized at different levels here.

Comment: Programming is not what I do for a living. So, I've explained it the best that I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facade patter is more suitable for hiding some comlicated sub-system behind a relatively simple interface.

From what I can understand you have 2 different systems and you want to send the same request to both. You need to know what's the relationship between these 2 systems:

- If there is some form of preference of one system over another you'd use the Chain of responsibility: you'd send a request, if the first system can handle it, you get the result, if not, the request goes to the next system in chain, and so on.
- If there is some form of augmenation or enhancement of a result from one system by results from another, you'd use Decorator, so the request goes to the "outer" system first, it calls to the "inner" system, gets some results then decorates them with its own data and returns decorated results;
- If you just have 2 independent system you want to query in parallel, then use "just do it" pattern =)  Use some parralel primitives from your framework, send 2 requests, wait for both results, submit them to a merge function.

Hope this helps.